# Unable to add 7mb shapefile nor GeoJSONn into QGIS as a layer; Works in ArcGIS Pro though

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

The data in question, you can download as .geojson or shapefile: https://data.mississauga.ca/datasets/mississauga::mississauga-official-plan-2010-schedule-10-land-use-designations/explore

In the file browser I am not able to right click on it so I can add it as a layer to my project. Nothing happens and qgis freezes for a couple seconds. I can right click on the .geosjon file right above it just fine. Happens with the shapefile version of the data as well. Pic of my file browser:

[image]

Opening the shapefile in ArcGIS Pro loads just fine though. Anyone know why? The limit for QGIS I read is 2gb.

Comment: I had a try by downloading the GeoJSON file and adding it into a QGIS project by drag-and-drop. No issues at all.

Comment: What version of QGis? What operating system?

Comment: W10 latest version, QGIS version 3.34.0-Prizren.

Comment: @user30184 For some reason dragging and dropping works. Weird that when right clicking the layer context window does not show.

Answer (score 1):

In a New Project try opening the *Mississauga_Official_Plan_(2010)*Schedule_10*-_Land_Use_Designations.geojson* file that has been downloaded.

This opened straight away and was categorized by MOP.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to do it my way though? Or did you get the same error?

Comment: To remove the issue of the potential network issue, download the file. You cannot make changes to an online file it will be treated as read-only. QGIS will cache temporary files.

Comment: I have downloaded online files before and I was able to right click on them and select "Add layer to project". Such as the other files in the pic in my post which are from the same website. How does the file being online affect me being able to right click on it in the file browser and get the context window show?